# Предсказание результатов футбольных матчей

Tags: машинное-обучение

Нужно предсказать результаты футбольных матчей. Из тестовых данных у нас есть различные матчи команд, их счета и те минуты, на которых они забили голы. Довольно легко это сделать, если предположить, что голы i-той команды распределены по закону Пуассону с параметром ламбда_i. Как можно предсказать результаты без использования распределения Пуассона?

Comment: можно попробовать определить распределение по выборке, и далее использовать полученное распределение для предсказания

Comment: а есть кардинально другой метод? Без использования законов распределения. и как тогда можна использовать минуты, на которых забивали голы?

Comment: Чтобы предсказание было похоже на правду, оно должно на чем-то основываться. Без этого, любое событие можно считать случайным и достаточно  будет получать любое случайно число в качестве предсказание, однако и точность в этом случае будет соответствующая